# Get data from array with several object

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i would like to get the "-lists" data from an array with several objects:

```
[{...},{...},{...},{"-name": "Test", "-lists": [123, 456, 789]},{...}]
```

i tried with a filter function but it doesnt works :-(

this is the query where i would like to change the result to the value/array of "-lists"

```
             .findOne({ _id: serviceID }, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    res.json(err);
                } else {
                    try{
                        res.json(result.service.modules)
                        console.log(result.service.modules)
                    }catch(error){
                        console.log(error)
                    }
                        
                }
            })
```

Have someone an idea for me?

Best regrads & stay healthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of one of the approaches you can use to extract the value of an array nested in an object which is inside an array.

```js
const arr = [{ someValue: 1 }, { "-lists": [1, 2, 3] }];
const result = [];

arr.filter((val) => {
  if (val["-lists"]) {
    result.push(...val["-lists"]);
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: no problem! make sure to mark this as an answer so it will help other people who have the same problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `map` function of the array.

```js
const data = [
  {"-name": "Test", "-lists": [123, 456, 789]},
  {"-name": "Test", "-lists": [222, 333, 444]}
 ];
 
 const result = data.map((x) => x['-lists']);
 
 console.log(result);
```

This will return an array of the lists data which is an array in itself.